# Ionic - take a picture with camera and send it to Amazon S3

Tags: jquery, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ionic-framework

I am building an app with Ionic framework (angularjs + cordova).

I would like the user to be able to take a picture with his phone camera, and send it directly to an S3 storage on amazon aws.

I know how to take a picture, and get it's base64 and it's URI on the local file system:

[ngcordova - camera](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/)

I also know how to send a file to S3 through ajax using jquery

[Direct upload to S3](http://matthewhailwood.co.nz/direct-ajax-upload-to-amazon-s3-with-jquery/)

Now, the problem is that all the file uploads I found are using an "input type=file". How can I manage to pass the file to the uploader, using its local URI or the base64 encoded string ?

Comment: Do you need to use a file upload or can you just use a simple ajax request and put the base64 in to a json object? - To create a file from a byte array have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, by converting the file returned by the camera plugin to a blob, as file inherits from blob I could send it through the S3 uploader by defining a fake local file name

Here is the part of building the blob

```
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageUrl) {

            var getFileBlob = function (url, cb) {
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open("GET", url);
              xhr.responseType = "blob";
              xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
                  cb(xhr.response);
              });
              xhr.send();
            };
            var blobToFile = function (blob, name) {
                blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
                blob.name = name;
                return blob;
            };
            var getFileObject = function(filePathOrUrl, cb) {
               getFileBlob(filePathOrUrl, function (blob) {
                  cb(blobToFile(blob, 'test.jpg'));
               });
            };

            //File created
            getFileObject(imageUrl, function (fileObject) {
               deferred.resolve({imageUrl : imageUrl, fileObject : fileObject});
            }); 
          }, function(err) {
            // error
            console.warn(err);
            deferred.reject(err);
          });
```